# Como obter múltiplas chaves em JSON com PHP?

Tags: php, json

Como obter dados com `foreach` através do `JSON` desse tipo:

```
{
    "12": {
        "0": {
            "9678": {
                "920": {
                    "224": {
                        "657": "José da Silva"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "0512": {
                "987/21": {
                    "233": {
                        "652": "Maria Silva"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi. Você só quer uma lista simples com os nomes "José da Silva" e "Maria Silva"?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função nativa "json_decode" do PHP

```
$json = json_decode('{"12":{"0":{"9678":{"920":{"224":{"657":"José da Silva"}}}},"1":{"0512":{"987/21":{"233":{"652":"Maria Silva"}}}}}}', true);

foreach ($json as $obj) {
    var_dump($obj);
}
```

**Edit**

Adicionei um parâmetro `true` ao json_encode para retornar os dados em formato de array e não objeto.

Comment: Eu preciso armazenar esses valores dentro do banco de dados. Portanto, eu preciso obte-los separadamente.

Comment: Fiz uma pequena correção no código, adicionei um parâmetro `true` a função para que você possa retornar os dados em formato de array e não objeto como era inicialmente.

Sobre adicionar os dados separadamente pelo seu json temos um problema, você não utiliza uma sequência lógica para os dados, não pode se utilizar de um incremento para recuperar os dados.